# How to make a recursive query dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

How to make a recursive query dynamically ?

Let's say that :

`QuantityDate` may be :

```
Month 3  The first quarter 
Month 6  The second quarter
Month 9  The third quarter
Month 12 The fourth quarter
```

If the user select the second quarter `6`

> Then I will sum the data in first quarter + the data in second quarter

If the user select the third quarter `9`

> Then I will sum the data in first quarter + the data in second quarter
>   + the data in the third quarter

etc ...

**My Query is like this :**

Here the user select the second quarter `(6)`, So I sum first Quarter data + second Quarter data like this:

```
,((ISNULL(d.SalesCost,0)*-1)/

(ISNULL(d.LocalSales,0)+ISNULL(d.Exporting,0) --The selected quarter data
+
(SELECT ISNULL(e.LocalSales,0)+ISNULL(e.Exporting,0)--The First Quarter
FROM CTE e
WHERE e.[Year] = d.[Year] 
AND e.period =2
AND e.PeriodTypeId =2 
AND e.CompanyId = d.CompanyId
AND MONTH(e.QuantityDate)=3))) AS Tot1,
,d.QuantityDate
FROM CTE d 
INNER JOIN CTE t 
ON d.[Year] = t.[Year] 
AND d.period = t.period
AND d.PeriodTypeId = t.PeriodTypeId
AND d.CompanyId = t.CompanyId
AND d.QuantityDate =t.QuantityDate
WHERE  d.[Year] IN (2016,2015) AND d.PeriodTypeId =2 AND d.Period =2
AND YEAR(d.QuantityDate)IN (2016,2015) AND MONTH(d.QuantityDate)=6
ORDER BY d.CompanyId, d.[Year] DESC
```

---

My Whole query:

[Query](http://pastebin.com/Yr2vzYe9)

---

Sample Data :

Let's say Quantity Table like this :

```
LocalSales  Exporting  QuantityDate
 15           20       1-3-2016
 22           80       1-6-2016
 40           20       1-9-2016
```

When the user select the second quarter i get both the first and the second quarter data in `CTE d`

```
 15           20       1-3-2016
 22           80       1-6-2016
```

Then i Join it with `CTE e`

And If say that `SalesCost` = `-20` for example

Then `tot1` should  = `20/((15+20)+(22+80))`

Comment: You should edit your question and show the original data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I edit the question , Could you take a look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion.  Just a cumulative sum.

It is hard to see what your data looks like, but the query might look something like this:

```
SELECT companyid, quarter(QuantityDate) as qq,
       SUM(COALESCE(e.LocalSales, 0) + COALESCE(e.Exporting, 0)) as quartersales,
       SUM(SUM(COALESCE(e.LocalSales, 0) + COALESCE(e.Exporting, 0))) OVER
           (PARTITION BY companyid, order by quarter(QuantityDate)) as running_sum
FROM t
WHERE e.[Year] = d.[Year] 
GROUP BY companyid, quarter(QuantityDate);
```

Your original data layout is unclear, but this should be pretty easy to follow.  You want to use window functions, not recursion.

Comment: My query is large so i paste it in :http://pastebin.com/Yr2vzYe9
where `period` is the `quarter number` and `periodtypeid` is the type :`annual` or `quarter`

Comment: I try to simplify the query by removing and data not related to the problem , Could you take a look at the query please : http://pastebin.com/Yr2vzYe9